# Como guardar todos los items de un listbox en una lista tipo objeto

Tags: c#, c#-8.0

tengo una listbox de alumnos que fueron agregados de otros listbox, necesito guardar los alumnos que fueron agregados a mi nueva listbox a una lista de alumnos pero me da un exa excepcion de:
System.InvalidCastException: 'No se puede convertir un objeto de tipo 'System.String' al tipo 'Entidades.Alumno'.'

```
 private void btnAgregar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (lsbSinSala.Items.Count > 0)
            {
                int index = lsbSinSala.SelectedIndex;
                lsbConSala.Items.Add(lsbSinSala.SelectedItem);
                lsbSinSala.Items.RemoveAt(index);
                foreach (Alumno item in lsbConSala.Items)
                {
                    ListaAlumConAula.Add(item);
                    MessageBox.Show(ListaAlumConAula.ToString());
                }

            }
        }
```

Comment: Coloca el codigo entero para ver de que son las listas que manejas. El error es facil de detectar pero falta codigo.

Comment: public List<Alumno> ListaAlumConAula { get; set; } necesito agregar a esa lista los items que estan guardados en lsbConSala

Comment: Queres rellenar una List<Alumno> desde lsbConSala, pero esa lista con que objetos esta rellenado? Ahi esta el problema del Cast